# Using API key with Gender package in R

Tags: r, api-key

I'm using the [Gender](https://rdrr.io/cran/gender/) package in RStudio to determine gender from a dataset of names by connecting to the [Genderize](https://genderize.io/) API. The number of requests I have to make exceeds the daily allowance so I've just bought a subscription.

However, unlike other packages that connect to Genderize (e.g. genderizer, gendered), I can't work out how to include the API key in the code (adding the API key and alternative wordings are not recognised, e.g.

```
gender(jop_authors_df$names, method = "genderize", apikey = "myapikey").
```

One easy fix is just to spread this out over days to not exceed the daily limit but I would ideally like to complete this more quickly (given I just bought a subscription).

My questions:

1. Does anyone know how to connect an API key to the Gender package?
2. Is there a way to use the httr package via GET or setting sysenv to connect to the Genderize API with the key?

The issue that I'm stuck on for question 2 is that the API for Genderize suggests requests using API key be phrased as "https://api.genderize.io?name=peter&apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}" (i.e. the request is in the middle of the URL and API key).

I'm an R novice so apologies for my silly questions/phrasing.

Comment: Hi ekk, Welcome to stack overflow. Can you include a bit of data and a few lines of code to see what you've tried already? Thanks!